# iOS Can I control the Apple watch or the smartphong using an external joypad?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I have a Bluetooth joypad and I would like to use it to scroll through the menus and to use different apps in the iPhone and in the Watch.
What are the possibilities of implementing this peripheral input? What can I do?

To be clear: so far I developed on android, I implemented a new launcher in the android wear that I control with the joypad. the joypad communicates with the smartphone and then the smartphone controls the smartwatch. I would like to understand the limits and possibilities of the iOS in this field.